# How to add custom colors to css variables in chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, css-variables, chakra-ui

This is in my index.js

```
<ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
<ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
  <App />
</ChakraProvider>
```

This is in my landing-header.jsx file

```
<HStack border="2px">
  <ButtonGroup  variant="ghost"  spacing={4}>
    <Button textColor={useColorModeValue('custom.100','custom.200')} size="md">Save</Button>
    <Button size="md">Cancel</Button>
    <Button size="md">Save</Button>
    <Button size="md">Cancel</Button>
    <Button size="md">Save</Button>
    <Button size="md">Cancel</Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</HStack>
```

And this is my theme.js

```
 const styles = {
  global: (props) => ({
    body: {
      bg: mode('#6cb6ff', '#003a75')(props),
    },
    
  }),
  colors:{
    custom:{
        100:'#6cb6ff',
        200:'#003a75'
    }
}
};

const config = {
  initialColorMode: 'system',
  useSystemColorMode: true,
};

const theme = extendTheme({ config, styles });
export default theme;
```

I have followed the instructions [here](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/css-variables) but it still doesnt work as u can see here [image]